# toctree dropdown menu

Tags: dropdown, python-sphinx, hidden, sections, toctree

I want to get a **dropdown menu** when **listing pages** in **Sphinx**. I am using **toctree**.

But when this list appears, all the subsections also appear in the list. Is there a way to either:

1. Get a dropdown menu or
2. Not show the subsections

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a dropdown you can use the dropdown directive.

```
.. dropdown:: Dropdown menu title

    Dropdown text only

    Dropdown text with an internal link :doc:`directory/file_name`
```

Keep in mind that in order to use the dropdown directive, you will need to install the dropdown directive by running `pip install sphinx-panels` in your environment.

Make sure to also add `'sphinx_panels'` to your `extensions` inside of your `conf.py` file.

You can find more examples for how to do that [here](https://sphinx-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dropdowns.html)